# Could I have some clearance on why one of my methods are being called ran first when I call it second?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, methods, adobe, runtime

When I run this program the "showAPplication" method runs first. I am just a little confused as why the "showApplication" method runs before the "complete" method? Why could this be happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <s:applicationComplete>
        <![CDATA[
            complete();
            showApplication();
        ]]>
    </s:applicationComplete>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function complete(): void {
                Alert.show("wewt");
            }

            private function showApplication(): void {
                Alert.show("Showing components");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I must be reading this wrong. Shortly after I posted this I figured out that the last "alert" is the alert you can see.

Comment: You should answer and close your own question, if it is no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure how to close. Could you tell me how?

Comment: "delete" link under your post

Comment: I only see link | edit | flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alert component does not block execution of ActionScript code. In other words, after the first Alert is shown, the code keeps running, even if you haven't clicked OK yet. The first Alert is there, but it is hidden under the second Alert because Alerts are always display on top of other existing content.